# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## How to resolve this length error

i am providing code where error occurred and i tried to resolve this but nothing is working out here.

I tried changing it useState into an array but it is still not working.

```
    const Chart = () => {
    const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setDailyData(await fetchDailyData());
        }

        fetchAPI();
    });

    const linechart = (
        dailyData.length
            ? (
              <Line 
              data={{
                labels: dailyData.map(({ date }) => date),
                datasets: [{
                    data: dailyData.map(({ confirmed }) => confirmed),
                    label: 'Infected',
                    borderColor: '#3333ff',
                    fill: true,
                }, {
                    data: dailyData.map(({ deaths }) => deaths),
                    label: 'Deaths',
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                    fill: true,
                }]
              }}
            />) : null
    );
```

this is index.js file

```
    export const fetchDailyData = async ()=> {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);

        const modifiedData = data.map((dailyData) => ({
            confirmed: dailyData.confirmed.total,
            deaths: dailyData.deaths.total,
            date: dailyData.reportDate,
        }));

        return modifiedData;
```

Comment: `await fetchDailyData()` this might not be returning array, or expected data, do `console.log(await fetchDailyData())` and check

Comment: Agreed with Vivek. Can you `console.log(data)` just after your axios call?